# Where is the Code of the class Class or any other Ruby Standard class?

Tags: ruby

I want to read the code that defines .attr_accessor for any Ruby Class.

Soon realised that I don't have any idea how to find it.

is there something like `AnyClass.source_location` that can make thing easy?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `attr_accessor` on Ruby-Doc.org.  You should quickly find https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor.  Hover over the description of `attr_accessor`, then click on the upper right corner where it says `click to toggle source`.

For full context, all the source `.c` files are itemized at the top left of the class documentation page.  Source code for Ruby is freely downloadable from https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the specific Ruby Implementation you are using.

In [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/), there are two definitions. The first definition is an extremely basic one that is used for the implementation of Rubinius itself. It lives in [`core/alpha.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/alpha.rb#L576-L586), the very first file loaded in the Rubinius Core:

```rb
class Module
  def attr_accessor(name)
    attr_reader(name)
    attr_writer(name)
    nil
  end
end
```

The full-featured definition is in [`core/zed.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/zed.rb#L233-L243), the very last file loaded in the Rubinius Core:

```rb
class Module
  def attr_accessor(*names)
    vis = Rubinius::VariableScope.of_sender.method_visibility

    names.each do |name|
      Rubinius.add_reader name, self, vis
      Rubinius.add_writer name, self, vis
    end

    return nil
  end
  private :attr_accessor
end
```

In [Opal](https://opalrb.com/), it is defined in [`opal/corelib/module.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/module.rb#L109-L112):

```rb
class Module
  def attr_accessor(*names)
    attr_reader(*names)
    attr_writer(*names)
  end
end
```

In IronRuby, the definition is in [`Src/Libraries/Builtins/ModuleOps.cs`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby/blob/master/Src/Libraries/Builtins/ModuleOps.cs#L415-L427):

```cs
// thread-safe:
[RubyMethod("attr_accessor", RubyMethodAttributes.PrivateInstance)]
public static void AttrAccessor(RubyScope/*!*/ scope, RubyModule/*!*/ self, [DefaultProtocol, NotNull]string/*!*/ name) {
    DefineAccessor(scope, self, name, true, true);
}

// thread-safe:
[RubyMethod("attr_accessor", RubyMethodAttributes.PrivateInstance)]
public static void AttrAccessor(RubyScope/*!*/ scope, RubyModule/*!*/ self, [DefaultProtocol, NotNullItems]params string/*!*/[]/*!*/ names) {
    foreach (string name in names) {
        DefineAccessor(scope, self, name, true, true);
    }
}
```

In [JRuby](https://jruby.org/), it is defined in [`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyModule.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyModule.java#L2805-L2822):

```java
@JRubyMethod(name = "attr_accessor", rest = true, reads = VISIBILITY)
public IRubyObject attr_accessor(ThreadContext context, IRubyObject[] args) {
    // Check the visibility of the previous frame, which will be the frame in which the class is being eval'ed
    Visibility visibility = context.getCurrentVisibility();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        // This is almost always already interned, since it will be called with a symbol in most cases
        // but when created from Java code, we might getService an argument that needs to be interned.
        // addAccessor has as a precondition that the string MUST be interned
            addAccessor(context, TypeConverter.checkID(args[i]), visibility, true, true);
    }

    return context.nil;
}
```